# ListView CachingStrategy RecycleElement problem - GC called every second, app slows down

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with ListView's cachingstrategy in Xamarin Forms. I set cachingstrategy to recycleelement, my view cell uses custom control with lottie file, here is the code:

```
<ViewCell>
        <controls:CheckboxLottie IsChecked="{Binding checkboxChecked}" />
</ViewCell>
```

The code of my custom control looks like this:

```
  public class CheckboxLottie : AnimationView
    {
        public static BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(CheckboxLottie), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: IsCheckedChanged);

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
        }
        static void IsCheckedChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (!(bindable is CheckboxLottie cb))
                return;

            if ((bool)newValue)
            {
                cb.PlayMinAndMaxProgress(0.98f, 0.99f);
            }
            else
            {
                cb.PlayMinAndMaxProgress(0.0f, 0.015f);
            }
        }

        public CheckboxLottie()
        {
            Animation = "checkbox.json";
            AutoPlay = false;
            Clicked += Checkbox_OnClick;
        }

        void Checkbox_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsChecked = !IsChecked;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I set ListView's cachingstrategy to recycleelement, my constructor is called all the time, even if I remove the page with listview. It causes memory leaks and decreases my app performance.

Did I miss something in my custom control code? How can I release it from memory when I remove the page with listview? I tought that garbage collector will do it for me.

Here is my xaml page code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Model"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.ListPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="toolTipTemplate2"  x:DataType="models:MyItem">
            <ViewCell>
                    <controls:CheckboxLottie IsChecked="{Binding checkboxChecked}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        
            <ListView SeparatorColor="Transparent" 
                          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                          RowHeight="{OnIdiom 190, Phone=190, Tablet=380}"
                              x:Name="listView"
                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                          
                  BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                          SelectionMode="None" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource toolTipTemplate2}" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And here is .cs file

```
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ListPage: ContentPage
    {
        public ListPage(List<MyItem> list)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listView.ItemsSource = list;
        }

    }
```

I also noticed, that in output those lines are printed all the time:

```
[Mono] GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 36 objects 36 opaque 0 colors 36 colors-bridged 36 colors-visible 36 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.19ms tarjan 0.04ms scc-setup 0.05ms gather-xref 0.02ms xref-setup 0.01ms cleanup 0.15ms
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 26.75ms
[Mono] GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 5.79ms, stw 8.16ms promoted 786K major size: 11600K in use: 10156K los size: 10240K in use: 8644K
```

It looks like garbage collector couldn't clean memory when cachingstrategy is recycleelement.

Here is viewcell with label, which also calls GC all the time.

```
<ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}"   
                                TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" 
                                 FontSize="{OnIdiom 24, Phone=24, Tablet=48}"/>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: The ListView has an ItemsSource, right?  1) How many items are there?  2) For a test, make the source an empty collection (no elements; nothing to display). Does your constructor still get called? 3) Another test, have just one element in the collection. Does your constructor still get called often? 4) If you are testing that constructor is called by setting a breakpoint, INSTEAD put a Debug.WriteLine there. So you can watch for those WriteLines in application output. REASON: Any time you continue from a breakpoint, I'm not sure if it needs to call constructor again or not. Want to avoid that.

Comment: Ok, I pasted the code. There are 20-30 items in my listview, recycleelement improve performance of my listview and it scrolls smooth. When the source of listview was empty collection, my constructor wasn't called. When collection is not empty and I put Debug.Writeline, it display string all the time, like in an infinite loop.

Comment: Hmm.  Not seeing any obvious reason. Add another Debug.Writeline, in ListPage's constructor. Want to know if that is getting called over and over also. If so, and you make the list have only one item, do you get just one Lottie constructor call per ListPage constructor call?  Or does it call Lottie a whole bunch of times, for the single ListPage constructor?

Comment: ListPage's constructor is called only once, I pasted Debug.Writeline and it printed one string. When list has only 1 item constructor is called all the time, only when list is empty everything works correctly. I pasted some logs from my output, when I navigate to page with listview GC is working all the time. It looks like XF bug, because when there is a XF control, for example Label, GC is also working all the time, and the app is slowed.

Comment: I've pasted ViewCell with Label, which also calls GC all the time and slow the app.

Comment: thanks. Sorry for prematurely editing title - I was sure that wouldn't happen. That's strange - going to look for that in a sample app on my pc. "slow the app" - when?  When scrolling?  Are GC calls once per second, or slower or faster than that?

Comment: GC calls are per seconds, maybe a little faster. The app works slowly when I several times navigate to page with listview, it depends on the phone or emulator. It looks like memory leak.

Comment: Do you know of Apple's instrument tool(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/walkthrough-apples-instrument)? maybe you can take advantage of it with the debug to find out the problem.

Comment: There's something missing in the above code. Show the *complete* ListView declaration, **with all its contents**. If that doesn't include the ViewCell, then show all code involved in associating ListView with ViewCell. REASON: I don't want to make any assumptions about what is causing this symptom.

Comment: Is this XF5? I was experiencing the same issue with the `RecycleElement` caching strategy. Then I found this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13992). As suggested, I disabled Hot Reload and the problem went away for me!

Comment: Yes, it's XF5. I replaced all listviews in my app with collectionview and it helped me, but there is still a bug with listview when caching strategy is recycle element.